# The name does not exist in the current context method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program that pulls int's from a method in a class into another class. When its pulled into the main program, it is supposed to run through an if statement to only display certain values. In the main Program class though, I'm getting the error that the name ### does not exist in the current context. If someone could take a look at this and tell me what I'm missing, it would be much appreciated. I'm having issues with the counter, die1 and die2 variables in the main Program class.

```
namespace DiceRoll
{
    public class RollClass
    {
        public void RollMethodDice()
        {
            int die1, die2, counter;
            // create Random number generator
            Random rndRoll = new Random();

            // Loop that counts the # of rolls from 1 to 100
            for (counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++)
            {
                // Random generators for each die
                die1 = rndRoll.Next(1, 7);
                die2 = rndRoll.Next(1, 7);
            }
        }

        public int GetDiceRoll()
        {
            return die1;
            return die2;
            return counter;
        }

        public int die1 { get; set; }
        public int die2 { get; set; }
        public int counter { get; set; }        
    }

    class Program
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the dice rolling program.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("This program will roll dice 100 times and display the roll where doubles land.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Rolls that were in doubles:");

            RollClass myRollClass = new RollClass();

            myRollClass.RollMethodDice();

            if (die1 == die2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Roll "+ counter + ": "+ die1 + " "+ die2);
            }
        }

        // Key stroke is needed to close console window so results are visible
        Console.ReadKey();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, it makes it *much* easier for people to read. Anyway, you've defined `die1` and `die2` in `RollClass` but you're trying to read them from `Program`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to declare

```
public int die1 { get; set; }
public int die2 { get; set; }
public int counter { get; set; }
```

in the `RollClass`, not in the `Program`. If you want to use them, use by writing instance name of the `RollClass` before the variable name

```
RollClass myRollClass = new RollClass();
if (myRollClass.die1 == myRollClass.die2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Roll "+ myRollClass.counter + ": "+ myRollClass.die1 + " "+ myRollClass.die2);
}
```

In addition, there seems to be "duplicate" names of `die1, die2, counter` in the `RollMethodDice` method and in the `RollClass` class. This is allowed. But in that case, by default, the class variables need to be called by using `this` keyword (`this.die1`) to distinguish it from the local variables `die1`

Also, the function you made

```
public int GetDiceRoll()
{
    return die1; //only this will be returned!
    return die2; //will never come here
    return counter; //will never come here
}
```

Will only return die1. If you want to return the three of them you should create a new `struct` or `class` containing the three variables

```
public struct DiceResult {
    public int die1;
    public int die2;
    public int counter;
}
```

Where you can replace

```
public int die1 { get; set; }
public int die2 { get; set; }
public int counter { get; set; }
```

with

```
public DiceResult diceResult { get; set; }
```

And put the function like this

```
public DiceResult GetDiceRoll()
{
    return diceResult;
}
```

And call the variables in the `Program` like this

```
RollClass myRollClass = new RollClass();
if (myRollClass.diceResult.die1 == myRollClass.diceResult.die2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Roll "+ myRollClass.diceResult.counter + ": "+ myRollClass.diceResult.die1 + " "+ myRollClass.diceResult.die2);
}
```

Hope that will help!

Comment: Thanks that helped a bunch. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

problem with your variable declaration

```
for (this.counter = 1; this.counter <= 100; this.counter++)
        {
            // Random generators for each die
            this.die1 = rndRoll.Next(1, 7);
            this.die2 = rndRoll.Next(1, 7);
        }
```

Comment: I made those changes but I still have the same errors I did before.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your program.

```
namespace DiceRoll
{
    public class RollClass
    {
        //int die1, die2, counter;  // <-- Field of class should be defined outside method.
                                    // <-- And since you used auto generated property below, these are not needed here.
        public void RollMethodDice()
        {
            // create Random number generator
            Random rndRoll = new Random();

            // Loop that counts the # of rolls from 1 to 100
            for (counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++) {
                // Random generators for each die
                die1 = rndRoll.Next(1, 7);
                die2 = rndRoll.Next(1, 7);
            }
        }

        public int GetDiceRoll()
        {
            return die1;
            //return die2;  // <-------- You cannot return multiple values in a method.
            //return counter;  // <----- Instead, an array point/reference is possible.
        }

        public int die1 { get; set; }
        public int die2 { get; set; }
        public int counter { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the dice rolling program.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("This program will roll dice 100 times and display the roll where doubles land.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Rolls that were in doubles:");

            RollClass myRollClass = new RollClass();

            myRollClass.RollMethodDice();

            if (myRollClass.die1 == myRollClass.die2)  // <--- You need use your class instance to access the property.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Roll " + myRollClass.counter + ": " + myRollClass.die1 + " " + myRollClass.die2);
            }
            // Key stroke is needed to close console window so results are visible
            Console.ReadKey();  // <--------- Method call should be stay inside a method, not a class.
        }
    }
}
```

And in one word, you really need to read some basic OOP book. For example [Head First C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514824). And [Online tutorial from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) are also helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Not to make excuses for myself but I'm only in the 2nd week of this class and it is a new language using a book provided that is not the greatest on providing information. If it wasn't for the fact I'm kinda burnt out at the moment from a long day at work and even longer evening, I probably would have caught most of the issues found here tonight without posting about it. My brain is pretty much fried at the moment. Again, thanks for pointing out the issues you did. I made several of the changes people have posted and it has resolved the issues I was having.